# Convert a linked list to an array of characters

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list

I wrote down this code in C to convert a linked list where each node contains a character and convert that list into a string. This is my code

```
struct node {
    unsigned char bit : 1;
    struct node *next;
};
   //Converts the linked list into a String 
char *list_to_bitstring( struct node *head ) {
    struct node *countNode = head;
    int count = 0;//Counts number of nodes
    while ( countNode != NULL ) {
        count++;
        countNode = countNode->next;
    }
    char *result = (char *)malloc( sizeof( count + 1 ) );
    struct node *temp = head;
    int i = 0;
    while ( temp != NULL ) {
        result[i] = temp->bit;
        i++;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    result[i] = '\0';
    return result;
}

//main method
int main() {
    struct node *head1 = bitstring_to_list( "111" ); //Converts a String into a linked list 
    char *result = list_to_bitstring( head1 );
    printf( "%s", &result );
    return 0;
}
```

But the output is this-

```
│
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this output. Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Please format your code with proper indentation so that it is readable.

Comment: I didn't check the accuracy of your function call (use a debugger for that), but you should have `printf("%s", result)` not `printf("%s", &result)`. `result` is already a `char *`. `&result` is not the address of a string. It's the address of a pointer to the string.

Comment: I used printf("%s", result) instead of ("%s", &result) and I got this -   . It's like 3 boxes with 0s and 1s in it but it doesn't show up when I paste it here for some reason

Comment: That doesn't make `printf("%s", result)` wrong. It means at least one of your functions isn't working correctly.

Comment: The boxes with 0s and 1s are either 00 or 01 in hex. That's because your string doesn't contain the characters `'0'` and `'1'`. It contains the integer values 0 and 1.

Comment: @user3386109 so how do I convert the integer values into characters ?

Comment: @lurker Yeah, You're right. printf("%s", result) is the right way to do it

Comment: Add `'0'` as in `result[i] = temp->bit + '0';`

Comment: @user3386109 That worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the comments under the question, there are two problems in the code:

1. The `printf` is printing the address of the pointer, not the string itself. The `printf` should be `printf("%s\n", result);`
2. The elements of the string need to be converted to the characters `'0'` and `'1'`. This can be done by adding `'0'` to each element of the string, e.g. `result[i] = temp->bit + '0';`